# Trigger fires on specific Boolean field change

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wish to setup an alert for when a specific user account is locked in an application with a MSSQL database, because something in the application is locking it!

I thought either a Trigger or Stored procedure to send an email when the "IsLocked" boolean field is true on the specific user record.  Is this possible with a Trigger please?

I thought about something like the following but my concern with this is that if the trigger is busy while dealing with a different account that has been locked it may miss the relevant account becoming locked.  A stored procedure is an alternative but then there is the problem of it needing to run every 5 minutes for example to check the record and then stop after the first alert email is sent!!

```
IF UPDATE (IsLocked)
BEGIN
DECLARE @varLocked varchar(30)
  SELECT @varLocked = IsLocked FROM Users where UserId = 'xxxx'
  IF (@varLocked = 1)
  BEGIN
    /* send email */
  END
END
```

Comment: Sending an email within a trigger is always a bad idea. If the email fails to send, for whatever reason, the transaction will fail and thus so will the `UPDATE`. I would create a table to log the data in, and then use agent to pool that table (on a regular basis) and then send an email if there is not data.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for prompt feedback.  So do you mean have a trigger to place a value in a table if the specific account field changes and also a stored procedure or agent to poll the table and if it has a value within then send the email?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: *"...it may miss the relevant account becoming locked"*, the trigger won't miss anything as it will fire on every update attempt.

Comment: @Larnu Okay.  So does my trigger basic code look sound?  Is there a danger that while firing from an IsLocked on another record it misses the account I want to monitor? Thanks

Comment: No, as it assumes that only one row will be updated, let me write some Pseudo-SQL for you.

Comment: It depends on what has caused the account to get locked. In case of incorrect attempts (assuming that is getting validated in your application) you can directly show up a lock message (instead of an email) right below the submit button

Answer (score 1):

The trigger you want will be something as "simple" as this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AccountLocked ON YourTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO YourLogTable (UserName, LogDateTime/*Other columns*/) --Don't forget to create your log table first!
    SELECT i.UserName, GETDATE()
    FROM inserted i
         JOIN deleted d ON i.IdColumn = d.IdColumn
    WHERE i.Islocked = 1 and d.IsLocked = 0;

END
GO
```

Then you simply need to create your SP which pages your log table and email you the relevant details.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and flag as the answer if works

Answer (score 0):

Inside the trigger :

```
WITH Accounts AS (SELECT UserId, IsLocked FROM INSERTED EXCEPT SELECT UserId, IsLocked FROM DELETED) 
SELECT UserId FROM [Accounts] WHERE IsLocked = 1 and UserId = 'XXXX'
```

This will return the account if it is updated from IsLocked = 0 to IsLocked = 1.

You can then work forwards from there.

Comment: Using Update() is not a good idea as it will fire even if IsLocked has been updated from a value of 1 to 1